# Is there a word for a person who frequently contemplates about how things might be in the future?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, epithet-requests

I used to think 'futurist' is the word to describe such a person, but then I realized, 'futurists' are highly experienced people who are usually given the title 'futurist', after they prove themselves in the real world. But, how about a person who wonders about the future, say, as a hobby. Is there a word to describe such a person. Anything relatable is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think you have an exaggerated view of what is required to call oneself a futurist, albeit a view that is propagated by futurists.

Comment: I know this is not what you are after, but in the name of vocabulary pleasures there is the word prognosticator https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prognosticator A person who foretells or prophesies a future event.

‘there are many prognosticators predicting the worst’

Comment: *Dreamer*? *Predictor*? There are a whole bunch of synonyms for people who "see" the future, but it's not at all clear if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: A tarot card reader, an astrologist, or (sorry in advance), a bullshit artist. :)

Answer (score 1):

The OED has entries for the terms ***futurology***, and ***futurologist***, also ***futurist***. (see below).

Wikipedia regards ***futurologist*** and ***futurist*** as synonymous. However the OED's treatment of the latter indicates other senses for the term ***futurist*** as well as its OED sense 2. which corresponds with ***futurologist***. I have reproduced all three OED senses below.

For this reason I would tend to avoid using *futurist* as it has other meanings. And I would use ***futurologist***. I first came across the word in the early 1970's when I read Alvin Toffler's *Future Shock* (1970).

OED ***Futurology***

The forecasting of the future on a systematic basis, esp. by the study of present-day trends in human affairs.

> 1946   A. Huxley Let. 29 Mar. (1969) 542   Thank you for..the
>   interesting enclosure on ‘Teaching the Future’. I think that
>   ‘futurology’ might be a very good thing.
>
> 1967   Listener 23 Mar. 397/1   Futurology, the systematic study of
>   trends which enable us to forecast the shape of things to come.
>
> 1969   New Scientist 11 Dec. 570/2   Futurology..cannot be turned into
>   a respectable ‘hard’ science merely by getting the economists and the
>   technologists to put some numbers to it.

***Futurologist***

> 1967   Listener 23 Mar. 397/2   Here we are with the automation
>   process which, according to well-known futurologists, will lead to
>   enforced leisure for a large part of the population.
>
> 1970   Financial Times 13 Apr. 7/1   American futurologist Herman Kahn
>   is wrong in seeing the 21st century as belonging to Japan.

***Futurist***

> 1. Theol    a. One who believes that the Scripture prophecies, esp. those in the Book of Revelation, are still to be fulfilled in the
>      future.
>
> 1842   G. S. Faber Provinc. Lett. I. iv. 88   Dr. Todd and Mr.
>   Mac-Causland..are alike staunch Antiprotestant Futurists.
>
> 1854   D. S. Desprez Apocal. Fulfilled i. 2   We have Præterists and
>   Futurists—one class of interpreters believing that the Apocalypse was
>   fulfilled in the first three or four centuries of the Christian æra;
>   another class maintaining that, with the exception of the three first
>   chapters, none of it is fulfilled.
>
> 1882   F. W. Farrar Early Days Christianity II. 227.
>
> b. attrib. passing into adj.
>
> 1878   H. G. Guinness Approaching End of Age Pref. (1880) 5   The
>   futurist school of prophetic interpreters.
>
> 1881   Church Times 25 Feb. 121   To give themselves up..to idle
>   futurist speculations.
>
> 2. One who has regard to or studies the future; a believer in human progress.
>
> 1846   in J. E. Worcester Universal Dict. Eng. Lang.    1936   G. K.
>   Chesterton Autobiogr. 25   The one thing forbidden to such futurists
>   was Looking Backwards.
>
> 1956   A. Toynbee Historian's Approach to Relig. vi. 79   The
>   futurists are revolutionaries who consciously and deliberately set out
>   to break with a disintegrating social past in order to create a new
>   society.
>
> 1964   E. M. Forster in Granta 15 Feb. 9/1   Traction Engine: I shall
>   pass often enough in the future. Punt: A Futurist! Better and better.
>
> 1971   Observer 10 Jan. 21/7   A man whose name had often been
>   mentioned respectfully by other futurists.
>
> 3. [After Italian futuristo, French futuriste.] An adherent of futurism. Also attrib. or as adj.
>
> 1911   W. J. Locke Glory of Clementina Wing xxii. 278   After that
>   they had gone to see the New Futurists.
>
> 1914   Star 16 Dec. 6/2   Small bullet-proof shields,..painted in
>   cubist patterns in futurist colours.
>
> 1915   W. H. Wright Mod. Painting 272   The famous Futurist statement
>   that ‘a running horse has not four legs, but twenty’.
>
> 1916   ‘B. Cable’ Action Front 128   Erratic daubs of bright colours
>   laid on after the most approved Futurist style.
>
> 1924   C. Hamilton Prisoners of Hope 129   The walls..were covered
>   with the raw and confused handiwork of the people who called
>   themselves futurists because they had never been taught how to paint.
>
> 1958   Times Lit. Suppl. 31 Jan. 58/1   Trotsky writes superbly on the
>   literary ‘fellow-travellers’, Alexander Blok, and the Futurists in
>   particular.

Comment: Good to know, albeit I am more inclined to know what a person who has a hobby to contemplate about the future can describe himself as. A person with such a hobby can't really describe himself using either of the words 'futurologist' or 'futurist', can he?

Comment: How about "science fiction writer" or "SF fan".  (Not "sci-fi", please.)

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this? This is the technical term for a person who projects the future based on scientific numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Forecaster** (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forecast)

forecast (noun) has various synonyms:   prediction, prophecy, forewarning, prognostication, augury, divination, prognosis.

Consciously considering the future when taking current actions is a human characteristic and influences many decisions.  A good number of people earn their livings forecasting weather, climate, interest rates, technology change, product demand, and so forth.  As a hobby you might call the person a futurist, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

a **soothsayer**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/soothsayer)

> One who claims to be able to foretell events or predict the future